# Failed to upload a local image file onto google doc with format converted

Tags: google-docs-api

For public link it works fine, but in my case I need upload a image file from local disk. I converted the image into base64 format, and write the html file into local disk as well, that html file can be opened in browser with image showing, but the document in google doc just an empty file, even I drag that html file into google docs the image still not there. My code is below:

```
DocsService client = new DocsService("testappv3");
client.setUserCredentials("username", "password");
File file = new File("c:/test.bmp");
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

int read;
byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buff, 0, read);
}
out.flush();

String base64 = Base64.encode(out.toByteArray());
String mimeType = DocumentListEntry.MediaType.fromFileName(file.getName()).getMimeType();
String html = "<html><body><img src=\"data:" + mimeType + ";base64," + base64 + "\"/></body></html>";


URL destFolderUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/<FOLDER_ID>/contents");
DocumentEntry newDocument = new DocumentEntry();
newDocument.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("test"));
newDocument.setMediaSource(new MediaByteArraySource(html.getBytes(), "text/html"));
newDocument = client.insert(destFolderUrl, newDocument);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look my experience level is only a few years so I could well be wrong but .... My understanding is that you can no longer use

```
client.insert(destFolderUrl, newDocument);// but now must use ResumableGDataFileUploader


new ResumableGDataFileUploader.Builder(client, new URL(uploadLink), mediaFile, null )
```

hopefully someone with more knowledge will confirm or deny

Comment: Resumalbe file uploader will upload image into Google Doc with original format, this will cost the storage usage also cannot retrieve back via DocumentList API. Google has raise this issue as a buge, please see Issue 3101 http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3101